# New Routes in Codeigniter - 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am working on an existing project on CodeIgniter and there was a need to create new routes. Existing routes work correctly, but new ones give a 404 error. Even when I make a copy of the route and controller, I also get a 404 error.

```
    $route['offer/list'] = "offer/list_offers"; 
    $route['offer/list1'] = "offer/list_offerss";
```

Second is copy.

Comment: `"offer/list_offerss"; ` - do you want double `s` at the end of method name?

Comment: Can you inform us which class is the controller 'Offer' extending to?

Comment: plz add some code or Offer controller's methods

Answer (score 0):

For an example.

[image: Routes]

After you added the routes, always create the Controller after that and call the view.

[image]

Note :
Don't use my $this->loadviews()...
Use the default

```
$this->load->view('phpNameWithoutTheExtension');
```

I use $this->loadviews() because i have another libraries that controll the view.